# problem in binding tkinter labels in the case a list of them is constructed using *

Tags: python, list, tkinter, widget, asterisk

What is difference between these blocks of code? The first one results in all the labels being placed at the last column, overlapping each other. Thank you in advance.

````
list_of_labels = [Label(root, text = '-')]*3
for i in range(len(list_of_labels)):
   list_of_labels.grid(row = 0, column = i)
#2.
list_of_labels = []
for i in range(3):
   list_of_labels.append(Label(root, text = '-'))
   list_of_labels[i].grid(row = 0, column = i)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your first case code is wrong:

```
list_of_labels = [Label(root, text = '-')]*3  # <-- create array of 3 items refer to same Label
for i in range(len(list_of_labels)):
   list_of_labels.grid(row = 0, column = i)  # <-- should be list_of_labels[i].grid(...)
```

The correct code should be:

```
list_of_labels = [tk.Label(root, text = '-') for _ in range(3)]
for i in range(len(list_of_labels)):
   list_of_labels[i].grid(row = 0, column = i)
```

*Note: The second case of your code is the prefer way.*

Answer (score 0):

The first case is only creating one Label.  The list then points to it three times.  Only the last `grid()`, at column 2, is active once `mainloop` starts.

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()

labels0 = [tk.Label(root, text = 'Test')] * 3
# Creates ONE Label and references it 3 times!!
for i in range(len(labels0)):
    labels0[i].grid( row=0, column = i )

labels1 = []
# Creates 3 Labels and references each one once. 
for i in range(3):
    labels1.append( tk.Label(root, text = 'Test '+str(i)))
    labels1[i].grid( row=1, column=i )

print('Labels0: ', labels0 )
# Labels0:  [<tkinter.Label object .!label>, <tkinter.Label object .!label>, <tkinter.Label object .!label>]
# One Label referenced 3 times in the list

print('Labels1: ', labels1 )
# Labels1:  [<tkinter.Label object .!label2>, <tkinter.Label object .!label3>, <tkinter.Label object .!label4>]
# 3 different Labels 

root.mainloop()
```